# Birt 4.2.2 new font issue with linux

Tags: linux, fonts, birt

I am using a new font on Birt 4.2.2 which is working fine on developers Windows machine, but not working on our Linux server which uses Websphere Application Server V8. I have changed the fontsconfig.xml as per this [link](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php/topic/28406-fonts-rendered-different-when-generating-pdf-report/) and I had the same issue.
Although, I can see that Birt processed my new fonts directory on the application server log file. Kindly advise.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted so others can benefit from your experience?

Comment: I already tried to do that, but I am a new user and I can't do that until 4 hours :S

Comment: I will do it after this period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue using below steps :

1- I executed those commands on the fonts directory (mkfontscale - mkfontdir)

2- Then I got the fonts encoding from the output files.

   Output is something like that :

   arial.ttf -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso10646-1

3- I got iso10646-1 and all other encoding and put them on font-encodings section on fontsconfig.xml file

4- Then I added the font names under font-aliases section on fontsconfig.xml


And it works fine.

The issue was the font encoding wasn't properly set while rendering the PDF for some reason. So, I mapped the fonts encoding to the font names.


Thanks a lot for all who replied.

Comment: Sorry, I can't mark the question as answered until 2 days as I am new user.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy your font file under ../jre/lib/fonts directory and run commands "mkfontscale" and "mkfontdir". Restart application server after this.

Comment: I already did this step with no luck. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: That's not a Birt limitation, that's a jvm limitation, only recent jvms (like openjdk) got fixed to work with fontconfig and modern font formats on unix.

Comment: You're right on the first part, this is not a birt limitation, but it's an issue with font encoding.
Thanks a lot.